# Does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Tags: swift, uikit

Hi I am making an app where I use CombineDataSources to update the data of my tableView.

I'm trying to make a form controller, like the one in the configuration app, they are different cells that share a protocol.

```
      var data = PassthroughSubject<[Section<FormModel>], Never>()
    //Type 'FormModel' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

    public protocol FormModel: AnyObject {
        var id: String { get }
        var title: String { get }
        var subtitle: String? { get }
        var type: Form_Configuration { get }
        var tintColor: UIColor? { get }
        var iconName: String? { get }
        
        var accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType { get }
    }

    open class SwitchFormModel: FormModel, Identifiable {
        public var id: String = UUID().uuidString
//
    }


    open class TextFieldFormModel: FormModel, Identifiable {
        public var id: String = UUID().uuidString
//
    }
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't let me pass the protocol to Section of the CombineDataSources library

```
public protocol SectionProtocol {
    associatedtype Element
    
    var header: String? { get }
    var footer: String? { get }
    var items: [Element] { get }
}

public struct Section<Element: Hashable>: SectionProtocol, Identifiable {
    public init(header: String? = nil, items: [Element], footer: String? = nil, id: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id ?? header ?? UUID().uuidString
        self.header = header
        self.items = items
        self.footer = footer
    }
    
    public let id: String
    
    public let header: String?
    public let footer: String?
    public let items: [Element]
}

extension Section: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Section<Element>, rhs: Section<Element>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension Section: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

extension Section: RandomAccessCollection {
    public var startIndex: Int {
        return items.startIndex
    }
    
    public var endIndex: Int {
        return items.endIndex
    }
    
    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return items.index(after: i)
    }
    
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Element {
        return items[index]
    }
    
    public var count: Int {
        return items.count
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: A protocol cannot conform to Hashable (because it cannot conform to Equatable). You cannot have a `Section<FormModel>`. From the code you've provided, I'm not certain why Section.Element requires Hashable, but you will need to either change Section, or pass a concrete type (for example, by creating a concrete type-eraser), but you may want to rethink the design or discuss with whoever maintains CombineDataSources. You may want to look at how ViewBuilder is implemented to see how this problem is addressed in SwiftUI (even if you're not using SwiftUI here).